# Git subtree export and re-import woes

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have a larger git repository (A) that shares a certain amount of code with another project (B) of mine. To make maintenance easier, I decided to have a third repository with the common code (C) which will then be used via `git subtree`.

I prepared everything in A (putting the common code in folder "sub") and used the procedure described in [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository) to create C

Now that I have C with just a few commits, I wanted to put it back into A, folder sub. I used the approach described in http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/using-merge-subtree.html which worked insofar as all commits for the subfolder were now duplicated. I didn't quite mind this, however now I am stuck with no idea how to continue working with this subdirectory.

I made additional changes in A/sub which I want to push to C. As described in [git subtree push changes back to subtree project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081681/git-subtree-push-changes-back-to-subtree-project) I used

```
git subtree split --prefix sub -b split-branch
```

to create a branch with just the subtree. This takes a bit of time, but finishes successfully. Doing

```
git checkout split-branch
git push remote-c master
```

gives me

```
failed to push some refs to "remote-c"
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
```

but a `git pull remote-c master` says I'm already up-to-date.

How do I resolve this situation?

*EDIT1*: I tried to reproduce the problem with a small test script. Executing this script:

```
( cd testC; git init --bare )
( cd testA; git init )

cd testA
git remote add C ../testC

mkdir sub
echo subFile1 > sub/subFile1
echo subFile2 > sub/subFile2
git add sub
git commit -m "adding files"

echo FileA > fileA
echo FileB > fileB
git add fileA fileB
git commit -m "add root level files"

# extract subtree and push to C
git subtree split -P sub -b split-branch
git push C split-branch:master

# try to make an update in C
git checkout -b cmaster C/master
echo subFile2new > subFile2
git commit subFile2 -m "updated #2 in C"
git push
```

This results in

```
To ../testC
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '../testC'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. If you did not intend to push that branch, you may want to
hint: specify branches to push or set the 'push.default' configuration
hint: variable to 'current' or 'upstream' to push only the current branch.
```

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, I think a `git` submodule is a better solution than constant subtree merging/extracting.

Comment: I'd rather go back to CVS than using git submodule ;-) I tried this once and I still got nightmares.

Comment: FYI, http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/ describes some of my issues with submodules.

Comment: http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/ is indeed a good article, that I reference in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12078816/6309  and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12123311/6309, I would still recommend them in your case though

Comment: We did try submodules a while ago for a similar approach. This so terribly backfired that nobody wants to touch submodules ever again. The issue is that my project involves a lot of people with limited experience in git (sometimes any VCS) and submodules require a bit of a gentle hand. Apparently subtrees as well ;-) While in theory submodules are perfect here, their disadvantages are too high for us to be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a `git push -f` which seems to have worked. Still would like to know what exactly happened and why.

Comment: Careful, you might have pushed into `C/master` the `master` branch of your local repository.

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of `git push` is to try to push all branches to the current branch remote if you have same named branches locally and remotely. From the `git push` manual:

> The special refspec : (or +: to allow non-fast-forward updates)
>   directs git to push "matching" branches: for every branch that
>   exists on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of
>   the same name already exists on the remote side. This is the
>   default operation mode if no explicit refspec is found (that is
>   neither on the command line nor in any Push line of the
>   corresponding remotes file---see below) and no push.default
>   configuration variable is set.

In this case, since your current remote is `C` and you have both locally `master` and remotely `C/master` it will be pushed, and since the trees will not match at all the push will fail with the `master -> master (non-fast-forward)` message.

When you `git pull` to your branch it says `up-to-date` because you are pulling yo your current branch, which is up to date.

To modify this behavior of `git push` you need to setup the `push.default` value in your git config. Look for "push.default" in http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html

Answer (score 0):

My solution: upgrade git. :-)

Your test script succeeds for me, assuming the `testA` and `testC` directories already exist.  I'm using the latest version of git (v1.8.2.1), so perhaps they fixed something since you posted this.

```
$ mkdir testA testC
$ ./test.sh 
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git/testC/
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git/testA/.git/
[master (root-commit) 3d5644d] adding files
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 sub/subFile1
 create mode 100644 sub/subFile2
[master 398c203] add root level files
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 fileA
 create mode 100644 fileB
Created branch 'split-branch'
57fe3e8fc226d854b623f11444d82dc77fd45682
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 269 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../testC
 * [new branch]      split-branch -> master
Branch cmaster set up to track remote branch master from C.
Switched to a new branch 'cmaster'
[cmaster 07c7c89] updated #2 in C
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 285 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ../testC
   57fe3e8..07c7c89  cmaster -> master
```